# Why is caching usually disabled in test environments?

Tags: caching, testing, selenium, symfony1, automated-tests

On our applications we have a lot of functional tests through selenium.

We understand that it is a good practice to have the server where the tests are ran as similar as possible to the production servers, and we try to follow it as much as possible.

But that is very hard to achieve in 100%, so we have a different settings file for our server for some changes that we want in the staging environment (for example, we opt to turn e-mail sending off because of the additional required architecture).

In fact, lots of server frameworks recommend having an isolated front-controller (environment) for testing to easily achieve this small changes.

**By default, most frameworks such as [ours](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/15-Unit-and-Functional-Testing#chapter_15_sub_working_in_the_test_environment) recommend that their testing environment should have its cache turned off. WHY?**

If we want to emulate production as much as possible, what's the possible advantage of having the server's cache turned off when performing functional tests? There can be bugs that are only found with the cache on, and having it on might also have the benefit of accelerating our tests execution!

Don't we just need to make sure that the cache is cleared before starting a new batch of functional tests, the same way we clear the cache when deploying a new version to production?

A colleague of mine suggests that the reason for this is could be that cache can generate false-positives, errors that are not caused by badly implemented features (that are the main target of those tests), but of the cache system itself... but even if those really happen (I suppose it depends on how advanced is the way the cache is used), why would they be false-positives?

Answer (score 0):

To best answer this question I will clarify some points.

(be aware that this is based on my experience)

Integration tests using the browser are typically "Black Blox Tests" , which means that they are made ​​without knowledge of the code. That is, without knowing whether the cache is being used or not.

These tests are usually designed based on certain tasks that are performed during the normal use of the system. But, these tasks are chosen for automation depending on certain conditions of use (mainly reusability, and criticality/importance but also the cost of implementation). So most of the times, we will not need/wont to test caching behaviour.

**By convention, a test (any) must be created with a single purpose and have the less possible dependencies.** Why?

- When the test fails , we can quickly find the source of the failure.
- Smaller tests are easier to extend, fix, remove...
- We do not spend too much time, first debugging the test code and then
  debugging the system code.

Integration testing should follow this convention.

**Answering the question:**

If we want to check a particular task, we must isolate it as possible.

For example, if we want to verify that the user correctly logs in, we have to delete the cookies to be sure that they do not influence the result (because they may). If on the other hand, we want to test the cookies we have to somehow use an environment where they are not deleted.

so, in short:
If there is need to test the caching behaviour then we need to create an "isolated" environment where this is possible.

The usual integration tests purpose is to test the functionality, so the framework default value it's to have the cache disabled.

This does not means that we shouldn't create our own environment to test the caching behaviour.